# Change input name of a form before submitting

Tags: jquery, forms

I need to change inputs name value before submitting form. Already trying changing the values after the page loads and all DOM elements are accessible, but somehow the form validation does not work properly, so I wonder if it is possible to change input name values just after form is submitted.

I am trying using jQuery this way:

```
$('.et_pb_contact_form').submit(function (e) {
    var $form = $(this);

    console.log($form);

    $form.submit();
});
```

This is what the log shows:

[image]

I just need to change `input#et_pb_contact_firstname_0.input` to `input#firstname.input`

How could I do it?

Thanks in advice!

Comment: For what reason do you need to do this? Changing form control names at runtime is a massive code smell

Comment: `input#firstname.input` is the ID and class of the input, not the name.

Comment: Adding to @RoryMcCrossan - you may be better off creating a new hidden form and copying over values and calling submit on that. A cleaner way would be to just collect your values and use ajax to make the request in the format that is needed if that is an option..

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the names are the same as the IDs that you want to change. You can use `.each()` to loop over all the inputs in the form, and use a regular expression to remove the `et_pb_contact_` prefix and `_0` suffix.

You don't need to call `$form.submit()`, this happens automatically when the submit handler returns, unless it calls `e.preventDefault()`.

```js
$('.et_pb_contact_form').submit(function (e) {
    var $form = $(this);
    $form.find('.input').each(function() {
      this.name = this.name.replace(/^et_pb_contact_(.*)_0$/, '$1');
    }
    console.log($form);
});
```